"Spatial" data structure for range/KNN queries with similarity defined by kernel
I am currently looking for a datastructure to store datapoints that allows for range/KNN queries based on a similarity measure definte by a kernel function.
Essentially I want to solve the following problem:
Given point x* return all datapoints for that some kernel function k(x,x*) is above a certain threshold.
Ideally, the datstructures should also allow for updates, adding and removing points, as I need to add and remove a couple of points every once in a while.
Naively I could compute the kernel values for all datapoints but that seems very inefficient. I thought about using ball-trees (f.ex implemented by scipy) using a corresponding metric. This would for example be straight forward for the RBF-Kernel as I could then use the euclidean norm as a metric in the ball-tree. Is there something that works for more general kernel functions (and maybe even for "non-metric" ones like periodic kernels).
Also, I would creatly appreciate any performant python library that could be used for implementation.

If your dimensionality were small, say, 2 or 3, the classic KD-Trees could be used as long as the space is orthogonal, i.e the data points have classic Euclidean coordinates. But, am I correct in assuming that your space is very high-dimensional? KNN queries in KD-Trees are exponentially affected, in a negative sense, by the dimensionality of the space.

@Jason Thanks for your reply. I thought about using KD-Trees. Actually my datapoints are fairly low dimensional. However I thought that KD-Trees only allow for range queries in a box right. How could I then retrieve data points based on the kernel value? I am thinking f.ex about periodic kernels.

Yeah that's right, in two dimensions you would have a box, in three dimensions you would have a cube, etc. In general, my understanding is that for KD-Trees, you need a Euclidean space with orthogonal bases (coordinates). For nearest neighbors, your use case sounds like a perfect application for locality sensitive hashing. But for range queries, I have not studied enough to know something off the top of my head :(
